# Cannot show div popup even after a successful ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

I have a div

```
<div id="pop2" class="pop-up1" style="display:none;">
  <div class="popBox1">
    <div class="popScroll1">
      <h2></h2>
      <p id="p1_id"></p>
    </div>
    <a href="#links" class="close"><span>Close</span></span></a>
  </div>
  <a href="#links" class="lightbox1">Back to links</a>
</div>
```

I have an external file edit_invoice_details.php in which I want to post some data which I am doing through this jquery function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').dblclick(function(){
        //alert($("#myId2").text());
        //showeditDiv($( "#myId2" ).text());
        var invid=$("#myId2").text();
        var pid=$("myId").text();
        var dataString = 'inv_id='+ invid+'prod_id='+pid;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "edit_invoice_details.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {           
            alert("success");
            $("#pop2").show();
            $("#p1_id").html(html).show();
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I want such a table such that when someone double clicks on it the div should open. Success alert is working fine. but I am not able to show that div. The divs content should be edit_invoice_details.php. Response text maybe

Any help is appreciated

Comment: does it `alert("success");`??

Comment: try like this (interchanging)
            $("#p1_id").html(html);$("#pop2").show();

Comment: what about dataType:html ?

Comment: @Pilot yes it alerts success

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#pop2").style.display = "block";
```

if it dont work then there might be other problems. Let me know.

Comment: didnt work. I was also trying to alert(datastring); but no output was there still its enters the success function

Comment: Try to put `console.log("lol")` after the code i give. And see in the console log for any output.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes if you hardcode the property display in the html tag like you did here

```
<div id="pop2" class="pop-up1" style="display:none;">
```

when you tried to show the div it won't work, try set the display to none in the css instead of hardcode the css in the html tag, that happened to me and I fixed that way.

also with this code

```
   $("#p1_id").html(html).show();
```

you are now showing the #p1_id selector, you are showing what is inside the #p1_id, tried some like

```
$("#p1_id").html(html);
$("#p1_id").show();
```

let me know if works for you the two possible issues that I wrote.

Comment: `show()` will override the inline style... so i don't think this is where the problem is.

Comment: @Professor, can you look at the style of `pop2` after the success alert to see if the `display` has been changed?

Comment: if you want to see the result you can try  alert(html) which is the parameter from your success function to see what is returning your php, also can use firebug in the net tab, if not keep it simple, put only a label inside the #p1_id and see if it is shown when you tried show(), if not the problem is not with the php, is in the client side.

Comment: when I use alert(html) it is showing the correct edit_invoice_details.php content without any error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `&` here:

```
var dataString = 'inv_id='+ invid+'&prod_id='+pid;
```

Comment: for post also? anyways I will give it a try